# Linux Ubuntu System Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root

After I have given myself the access rights for directory `/usr` and all its contents with

```
sudo chown -R USER /usr
```

my Ubuntu 12.04 System totally fails. E.g. Internetconnection is not possible anymore, USB Stick is not detected.

I tried using

```
sudo chown -R root /usr
```

but without sucess.

Furthermore I thought about saving important files on my usb stick and reset/reinstalling Ubuntu, but unfortunately my stick is not detected anymore.

Reason for trying this was that I wanted to install a program but when trying to do so, I always got the message "program already installed" -> Only a few folders and files of the program within folder `/usr` were left -> so I thought deleting them would solve my problem. How can I give `root` back the rights for the folder `/usr` and its contents and will Ubuntu work afterwards?

Comment: Very bad idea!! Anyway what is the error when you isse chown -R root /usr?

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni : `sudo: must be setuid root`

Comment: OK try logging in console `CTRL+ALT+F2` and the reissuing the command. Since sudo is indsise the /usr dir its permissions have been changed. You can go back to X with `CTRL+ALT+F7`

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni : I only get `invalid login` when using `sudo chown -R root /usr` or `chown -R root /usr` or `chmod -R root /usr` or `sudo chmod -R root /usr`. Is there a way to rescue the linux system or at least my data?

Comment: Ok. Try with `su` then type your root password, then `/bin/chown -R root /usr`. su in is `/bin` so this should work in theory

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni : I typed in `su` in the terminal and got `su: problem with authentification`. when trying `/bin/chown -R root /usr` I only get `Not owner. Denied` for each file and folder.

Comment: Ok. Last try and then I've exhausted my options: `sudo -i`, type in root password, then `/bin/chown -R root /usr`

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni : Ok, did not help. When typed in `sudo -i` I got again `sudo: must be setuid root`

Comment: Right. Very last option, you should try and boot into single user mode. From there I think you can then try and change permissions. For Ubuntu I cannot help as I don't know it. Have a look in the documentation on how to achieve single user mode booting.

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni : I m already saving my files with linux reader under microsoft windows 7. Afterwards I will try to just reset Ubuntu to default settings.